# Comment multiple lines doesn't work in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I'm new to vim and I found that the steps online didn't work on my vim.
Usually, I do:
1, move to the cursor to the beginning of the first line
2, press shift-V (Ctrl+V will copy thing) to be Visual mode
3, select lines that needed to be commented
4, press shift-i to be insert mode and then type the comment symbols (e.g //)
5, press Esc. The online tutorial said the it will comment on those selected lines automatically, but it doesn't work on my vim.
I use Linux, and I installed [commentary.vim plug-in](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary). Not sure if the plug-in is the factor.
Thank you~

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. Perhaps this would be better suite for [Vim Stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Before 1 you have to be in command mode.

Comment: when you visually select those lines, what vim reports the "mode"? `visual line` or `visual block`?  I mean the mode in your vim status-line.

Answer (score 3):

Between step 3 and 4, after selecting lines before you press shift-i, you need to enter "Visual Block" mode which by default key binding is Ctrl-v

This is my key map for c/c++/c# commenting in vim:

```
:nnoremap <C-/> I//<Space><Esc>
:vnoremap <C-/> ^<C-v>I//<Space><Esc>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I totally missed the CTRL + v to get into visual block mode. Thanks for pointing that out.